# Android : Create transparent mask from black white bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap

I want to convert a bitmap mask in black and white in a transparent bitmap as in this example.

I do not want to work directly on the pixels (with a loop) to make it faster.

Do you have an idea ?

[image: Source]

[image: Desired result]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP didn't show **any effort**. Not in coding nor in searching.

Comment: Use the Google, Luke! https://github.com/siyamed/android-shape-imageview

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to include your images properly - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. I would also highly recommend you to provide code with what you have tried. Good luck!

Comment: Thank Wtower, I could not put the images like that because we had a minimum of 10 posts and I am a new user.

Answer (score 0):

The reality is that I searched for hours throughout the internet and I have not found a solution.

I want to use a black and white mask on a photo without a pixel by pixel processing (all that natively with Android).

I have almost the solution but the treatment is too long because it is a loop so pixel by pixel: https://gafurbabu.wordpress.com/tag/android-image-masking/